# How to copy an individual from an OntModel to another with Java Jena API?

Tags: java, jena, owl

I am using Jena to handle OWL data.
I am trying to copy an individual and its properties from an OntModel to another OntModel.

The heaviest way is to create a new individual and copy each property and each class into the new OntModel. But it doesn't seem very efficient.
I've looked into the Jena documentation but didn't find anything...

Does anybody know which is the best way to do so?

Thanks !

Comment: Since Jena is RDF-based (even though it provides an OntModel abstraction), it might be easiest to use a SPARQL query.  But what happens if the object of some property is another individual?  Should that individual be copied as well?  Alternatively, you could also create a model containing just the information you want and add it as a submodel of the other OntModel.